# CSS:Can't select text of child with user-select:auto, while parent has user-select:none

Tags: html, css

I am trying to code an input form with instructions throughout. I would like the text to not be selectable, but of course I would like the input to be selectable so that the users can modify their text easily.

My HTML looks something like this:

```
<div id="form">
<header> Some header text </header>
Instructions on what to do.
<form>
<label>first name:</label><input type="text" name="fname" />
<label>last:</label><input type="text" name="lname" />
<label>email:</label><input type="text" name="email" />
</form>
<div id="extras"> A bunch of separate notes and maybe a textarea box</div>
</div>
```

and my CSS looks something like this:

```
#form{ user-select:none; }
#form form input{user-select:auto}
```

A couple of notes:
I included all the css for various browsers in my actual code.
I tried user-select:text, and it did not work.
I have many bits of text separated into different sections, so I very much prefer to remove the ability to select as the default behavior and just apply the ability to select to the inputs. Applying code to make each little bit of text unselectable would be a pain.
Even if I did the above fix, I would still be curious about this issue.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as `user-select: auto;` You should use `user-select: text;`
[Your given code works,](http://jsfiddle.net/ELzga/) so you may want to include the rest of the code or link to it.